# WPF, debugging databinding

Tags: wpf, debugging, data-binding

I'm trying to understand the following part of an error message:

Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.DynamicResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '118' and line position '56'.

, what lines are the error referring to? No source files are mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you double click on the errors you will be taken to them.  What compiler are you using?  If its MSVS then it usually takes you right to the error.  IF you dont have lines numbers on then its through the tools/options/text editor/all languages/*then check the box that says line numbers.  If this doesnt help please provide more information.